# Treating the contents of a TeX-style group ({\blah ...}) as macro arguments

Tags: macros, tex-core

I am trying to make adjustments to a large document that uses TeX-style macros, like this:

```
{\defun SomeFunctionName arg1 arg2}
```

The `\defun` macro is defined as `\newcommand{\defun}{\tt}`.

Can I adjust this definition to retrieve the `SomeFunctionName arg1 arg2` part as an argument, to allow for a more complex definition? Fox example, if `defun` was a proper LaTeX macro, I could put a box around the text, or put something before and after, etc.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\defun}{\tt}

\begin{document}
\section{\defun SomeFunctionName arg1 arg2}
Call {\defun SomeFunctionName} to foo the bar.
\end{document}
```

How could I (for example) add some text before and after every invocation of `defun`? What is the general approach to handle the contents of `{\defun ...}` as an argument, short of editing all occurences?

To clarify: this is a large, two decades old document. I didn't write it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\defun{\expandafter\zdefun\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi}

\def\zdefun#1{A \fbox{#1} B\egroup}

\begin{document}
\section{\defun SomeFunctionName arg1 arg2}
Call {\defun SomeFunctionName} to foo the bar.
\end{document}
```

---

Here

```
\iffalse}\fi
```

expands to nothing so

```
\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi
```

expands to a single unmatched `{` but is a matching `{}` so can be included in a definition.

So given

```
 {\defun SomeFunctionName}
```

The `{` starts a group and

```
\defun SomeFunctionName}
```

expands in one step to

```
\expandafter\zdefun\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi SomeFunctionName}
```

and in the next step to

```
\zdefun{SomeFunctionName}
```

`\zdefun` has a normal `#1` argument which is delimited by the `{` we just inserted and  the `}` that was originally in the file. (Note this `}` was originally a group close delimiter, it is now used as an argument delimiter so doesn't close a group.)

So this expands in one step to

```
A \fbox{SomeFunctionName} B\egroup
```

and the

```
A \fbox{SomeFunctionName} B
```

gets typeset, and finally the

```
\egroup
```

closes the group started by the `{` in the original file.

Comment: ...again, what is going on here?

Comment: Wow, that's really cool.  I never really understood why `\iffalse` and `\iftrue` were useful.  Now I've got an idea.  So, cool.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not write `\iffalse{\else}\fi` instead of `\egroup`.  It seems to work when I try that too.

Comment: @A.Ellett  The iffalse trick is needed at the start but at the end it just takes 4 more tokens and is slower, even if more symmetric

Comment: @Werner words added

Answer (score 10):

My preferred approach would be: use the find-and-replace function of your editor of choice and replace `{\defun` with `\textdefun{`.

EDIT: As @Clément points out, this does not work in cases like `\section{\defun abc def}`. I am afraid those cases would elude even a more sophisticated regexp-based approach, because one would have to add an additional closing brace.

Comment: That actually breaks many things, in cases like `\blah{\defun ...}`

Comment: I'm apparently too dumb for `sed`, but in Ruby it would be `text.gsub(/\{\\defun\s+([^\}]*)\}/, "{\\defun{\\1}}")`; see [here](http://ideone.com/NrisQT). Of course, you will never be able to catch all (La)TeX intricacies with a single (readable) regexp (which is one indicator that (La)TeX sucks as a programming language) but if the original author adhered to *some* coding standard, you'll need only a few runs to get most things right. It definitely beats loading even more wicked (La)TeX on top.

Comment: @Raphael This breaks for simple things like `\{` in the source, or just `{\defun abc \emph{def} ghi}` Also, the document is still being edited from time to time, and I can't merge my changes back in, so re-syncing with the master branch would be a pain.

Comment: @Raphael I don't know of a single significant programming language that can be easily parsed by a regexp, at least without recursive regexps, due to the nested parentheses problem.

Comment: @Clément That's true, but many refactoring tasks don't need a full parse. (Oh wait, you can't even *parse* (La)TeX!)

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with `\aftergroup`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\defun{\aftergroup\newdefun\aftergroup{}}
\newcommand\newdefun[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Here {\defun SomeFunctionName arg1 arg2}}
Call {\defun SomeFunctionName} to foo the bar.

\end{document}
```

The same limitation as David Carlisle's answer holds: calls of `\defun` that don't appear inside a pair of braces will break. In the case of

```
\section{\defun Whatever}
```

the error will be when processing `\tableofcontents`. But `\section{{\defun Whatever}}` will behave well.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how this works.  It seems that the bracket after `\aftergroup` is serving double duty.  Shouldn't there be a problem with its closing bracket (the one immediately following it in the definition of `\defun`) being mismatched at expansion time?

Comment: @A.Ellett The `{` brace following `\aftergroup` is put aside, the following one balances the one before `\defun` and makes the tokens `\newdefun{` put aside by `\aftergroup` to be reinserted. It's good luck that the braces also keep happy the scanner of the replacement text. The fact that this works also in `\section` is just a coincidence.